# Implementing a smooth bottomsheet with 3 states (EXPANDED, HALF_EXPANDED, COLLAPSED) and a RecyclerView with loadmore/pull to refresh event

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

My app need implement a bottomsheet with 3 state (EXPANDED, HALF_EXPANDED, COLLAPSED)
I tried looking for some libs to support this but I didn't find, in the bottomsheet I need to implement a recyclerview display from bottom to up and some event as loadmore, pull to refresh.
I tried to implement with recyclerview with CoordinatorLayout but App working not smoothly.
please help.
any idea is good for me

implement a bottomsheet with 3 state (EXPANDED, HALF_EXPANDED, COLLAPSED)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.